# How to ignore files starting with a period using watchmedo?

Tags: python, watchdog

My file editor creates temporary files prefixed with a `.`.

I am running:

```
watchmedo shell-command -p '*.py' -R -c 'echo "${watch_src_path}"'
```

I see events for the temporary files as I am editing, then two events on file save (presumably because it does a delete and write).

I would like to see one event -- only when I save a file.

Is there a way for me to do this with just the CLI?  I am not interested in creating a python script and using the watchdog API directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `--ignore-patterns` (`-i`) switch.

```
watchmedo shell-command \
    -p'*.py' \
    -R \
    -c'echo "${watch_src_path}"'\
    --ignore-patterns="*/.*"
```

Note that watchmedo is matching on the full watch_src_path so your ignore pattern can't be as simple as `".*"` like you'd think at first. Also all the pitfalls of wildcards are in effect, so if you were doing something silly like working in a hidden directory `/path/to/some/.hidden/dir` then you'd have to have a fancier pattern.

You also might want the `--ignore-directories` (`-D`) switch if the directory-related event is causing you annoyance too (this one is just boolean, no argument needed).

Comment: Is it possible to filter the events so that I only see one event from a delete/write?

Comment: I think the second event you are seeing may be the directory change event; have you tried running with -D switch also?

Comment: Running `watchmedo log` showed me that it is an extra FileModifiedEvent -- the editor must be touching the file twice.  Thanks for the help.